# Inserting two 8 GB RAM sticks in the laptop

Tags: windows-10, memory

I am inserting two 8 GB RAMS in the laptop, will the RAM increase to 16 GB?
Because I am running a VMware virtual OS and My laptop has 8 GB RAM and it is lagging and hanging.

Dell Inspiron 15 3567

Comment: You need to supply more information. What laptop do you have? What RAM did you have before? What type of RAM do you have now? Is your operating system 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @NiallJones Dell laptop,Processor:intel i7 7th gen,64 bit OS,RAM:DDR3

Comment: We need the laptop model.

Comment: Dell Inspiration 15 3000

Answer (score 4):

Please see [this](https://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/inspiron-15-%283567%29) link.

Your laptop supports up to 32GB RAM, with 2 RAM slots. So, to answer your question. Yes, it will increase your RAM to 16GB, as long as you have got the correct type. In this case, it's DDR4.

To find compatible RAM, please visit the link at the top of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for description Actually it is dell inspiration 15 3567 with DDR4 8GB RAM

Comment: I will edit my answer then.

Comment: 16GB is max memory for that model....https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/inspiron-15-3567-laptop/inspiron-15-3567-setup-memory/specifications?guid=guid-75267cc5-58e3-40c7-a127-2d6c59fbba8d&lang=en-us

Comment: Moab, it is 16GB per slot and there seems to be 2 slots available for this laptop.